# Including jquery in a Redmine plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am trying to make a Redmine plugin that uses jquery.

I get conflicts, when I add the following line in my view:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasChildNodes' of undefined
prototype.js:5734
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent'
prototype.js:828
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachEvent'
```

The view is a hook.

If I remove the `<script src="">` , it works, but then I have no jQuery to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at it, the prototype library is also loaded. Usually a library will automatically load into the global scope by assigning themselves to the `$` variable.

To get jQuery working, just add  `$.noConflict();` after you load jQuery (see [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) on the jQuery API). This unloads jQuery from `$` and reassigns it to what it was before (prototype).

Then you access jQuery using the `jQuery` object and not the `$` shortcut.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
```

If you really wanted to use a shortcut variable (for example, `$j`), then you can assign it when doing the noConflict:

```
var $j = $.noConflict(); // Then use $j instead of $
```

Alternatively, you can create an anonymous function and assign jQuery to `$` within it. This is only done within the scope of the function (so prototype is still $ outside of the scope):

```
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
```

All of these (and a few other examples) are shown on the [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) page - so you might want to have a look there.